# Binary search tree object creation issue

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

It's my first question here so apologies in advance if i miss any guideline.

i am working on binary search tree for learning purpose for past 3 days and i am stuck with one issue for a day now. tried to debug it as much as i can. Also tried to search on internet to see if there is any help but no success.

i have 3 classes

main class
bst class
integerset class

integerset has this constructor

```
public IntegerSet(int arr[]) 
{
    this.bst1 = new BST();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        this.bst1.insert(arr[i]);
        this.magnitude = this.bst1.getSize();
    }

}
```

which create bst object and insert array elements to bst.

when i do this from main

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
iSet = new IntegerSet(arr);
```

it works all fine, but when i create another object

```
int[] arr2 = {4,5,6,7};
iSet2 = new IntegerSet(arr2);
```

after creation of 2nd object both has same bst in them which contains 2nd array. 
been trying to solve this but doesn't understand why this is happening both should have their own integer-set object with their own bst.

Comment: Have you declared `bst1` as `static`?

Comment: In integerSet the declaration is

private BST bst1;

Comment: in BST node and size are static

 public static Node root;
 public static int size;

Comment: the `static` modifier makes a class member the same across all object instances of that class. Try removing it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. well formulated question. if you are in doubt in the future, read [ask] in the [help] section!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do check implementation of `IntegerSet`. It should be like this:

```
class IntegerSet {
    private final BST bst = new BST();
    private int magnitude;

    public IntegerSet(int[] arr) {
        for(int val : arr)
            bst.insert(val);
        magnitude = bst.getSize();
    }   
}
```